# How can I filter for the `id`s that satisfies two different SQL database queries, where the same table is queried with both?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query:

`select * from sval where fid = 994 and val = 'XLON';` that returns

```
id      fid      val
100     994      's'
102     994      'd'
103     994      'd'
104     994      'd'
110     994      's'
140     994      's'
...
```

And a second SQL query: `select * from sval where fid = 900 and val = 'Equity'`; which returns

```
id      fid      val
101     990      's'
102     990      'd'
110     990      'd'
120     990      'd'
140     990      'd'
159     990      's'
190     990      's'
...
```

I want to write a query that filters for all rows where `id` is in both results - how can I do this?

So from the above rows, what I want returned is:

```
 id      
102       
110     
140
```

Because the above 3 `id` appear in both results.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't match your description. You have two queries. One checks val = `XLON`, one val = `Equity`, but you only show rows whose val is none of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INTERSECT`:

```
select id from sval where fid = 994 and val = 'XLON'
INTERSECT
select id from sval where fid = 900 and val = 'Equity';
```

Or do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to make sure both fid's are there.

```
SELECT id
FROM sval 
WHERE (fid = 994 and val = 'XLON')
   OR (fid = 900 and val = 'Equity')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fid) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you search for the IN operator + a subquery?
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-in/

```
select * from sval where fid = 994 and val = 'XLON'
AND id IN (select id from sval where fid = 900 and val = 'Equity')
```

Edit:

So in the subquery `select id from sval where fid = 900 and val = 'Equity'` you select all the ids which are satisfying your first conditions (fid = 900 and val = Equity), which means your return table looks something like this

id
101
102
110
120
140
159
190

Then you use the first part of the query to filter for fid = 994 and val = XLON **AND** the id of those rows has to be one of the ids you selected before in your subquery (see return table above).

Comment: It's not clear what the two conditions are the id's are satisfying from this answer. Could you make that a bit clearer in your response?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @rrufai Sorry for late response, just added some more details

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having` clauses :

```
SELECT id
FROM sval 
WHERE ( fid = 994 and val = 'XLON' ) OR (fid = 900 and val = 'Equity')
GROUP BY id
having count(*) > 1;
```